# Need to determine the Linux c++ library

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to build a legacy c++ project but can't determine one of its libraries used there.

I have the following includes somewhere in .hs:

```
#include <syslib/String.h>
#include <syslib/File.h>
#include <syslib/IOStream.h>
#include <syslib/Utils.h>
#include <syslib/Exception.h>
```

In .cpps the stuff related types are prefixed with 'sys' :

```
sys::String 
sys::String::format(...) 
sys::MemoryOutputStream
sys::Exception 
sys::byte_t 
sys::count_t
```

and so on.

Linker uses 'sys' lib to perform the linkage.

I understand that question sounds silly but I spent a whole day googling for this items.
Did someone ever see/use these types before? What is the name of library exports this?

Thank you.

Comment: Ouch, I feel your pain.  Googling for "syslib" and "iostream.h" has got to be a nightmare.  There is no possibility that source isn't archived somewhere, somehow in the company?  What platform/OS was it running on before you inherited it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your compassion :) This code was run in Ubuntu-based image at some embedded devices.

Comment: This almost looks like an ancient version of glibmm, but I'm not really sure.  Any other hints?

Comment: Another thought:  Are you sure this wasn't an in-house library?

Comment: Yeah, it seems this is some old in-house library, whose creator left the company before my hiring and the lib stuff was formatted out with his HDD. Sad( I guess this question has no sense now...